# Wamp and laravel installation, virtual host works but localhost not(Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server.)

Tags: apache, wamp

I've been installing WAMP on a windows machine, then I install laravel framework, make the virtual host configurations and now i work correctly with that virtual host. When i type on the browser http://laravel.dev/ the applications works correctly but when i try to work with other projects on localhost the browser show me the next message:

Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

---

FYI when i type this
localhost/phpmyadmin/

Works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is not laravel related.

Comment: You now are advised to create Virtual Hosts for all your projects even the ones in the www folder. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: Thank you so much RigssFolly, thats right!. I configure a virtualhost to C:\wamp\www and it works correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I just went to the `httpd.conf` file and checked if the following was correct:

```
# Virtual hosts
# Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: where to find httpd.conf